# Can no longer send auto-reply when I get an order from PayPal

Tags: paypal, cart

I am using PayPal shopping cart, and when I get an order -- either from EBay or from my website, I would send an auto-reply message thanking the customer for their order etc. This has worked out great because I set it up in my email program (Windows Live Mail) to send a reply when certain words are in the subject line (like "Payment received from", "Notification of payment received" etc.). It worked like a charm because the sender was the actual customer's email address, even though it came from PayPal.

Now, however, the sender is "member@paypal.com", so all of my notices are returned to me undelivered.

Is there a work-around that I can use to get these auto-reply messages sent to my customers?

Thanks for any ideas that you might have.

Jackson

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an IPN script to send out an email to your customers.  The IPN POST would contain the buyers email address.  Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to a transaction.  You can find more on IPN [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro).  Also off to the left hand side of the page some additional links relating to IPN, and you can also find some sample code for IPN [here](https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623) that may help you to get started.

```
<?php
// Revision Notes
// 11/04/11 - changed post back url from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
// For more info see below:
// https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services
// "ACTION REQUIRED: if you are using IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for Order Management and your IPN listener script is behind a firewall that uses ACL (Access Control List) rules which restrict outbound traffic to a limited number of IP addresses, then you may need to do one of the following: 
// To continue posting back to https://www.paypal.com  to perform IPN validation you will need to update your firewall ACL to allow outbound access to *any* IP address for the servers that host your IPN script
// OR Alternatively, you will need to modify  your IPN script to post back IPNs to the newly created URL https://ipnpb.paypal.com using HTTPS (port 443) and update firewall ACL rules to allow outbound access to the ipnpb.paypal.com IP ranges (see end of message)."


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use: 
    // $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use:
    //$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

//set email variables
$From_email = "From: from@mysite.com";
$Subject_line = "Payment Confirmation";

$email_msg = "Thanks for purchasing my item. Your order will be delivered in 3-4 days. We appreciate your business.";
$email_msg .= "\n\nThe details of your order are as follows:";
$email_msg .= "\n\n" . "Transaction ID: " .  $txn_id ;
$email_msg .= "\n" . "Payment Date: " . $payment_date;

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment

$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $payer_email;
$mail_Subject = $Subject_line;
$mail_Body = $email_msg;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);


}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation

$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $receiver_email;
$mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN POST";
$mail_Body = "INVALID IPN POST. The raw POST string is below.\n\n" . $req;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Chad, Thanks for the info.  I'll check out the links that you provided and post my results.

Comment: OK, I checked out the info about IPN and it is so far over my head I have a sore neck from looking up. I can't believe that for the average PayPal merchant, who is not a programmer, there is no simple option for sending an auto-reply to a customer the way we used to.  PayPal has really screwed me on this one.  I used to be THRILLED with PayPal, now, not so much.

Comment: It can be a bit much if you are not a programmer.  I have added a sample PHP IPN script that basically sends an email out to the buyer, that you could use and modify, and build off of.

Comment: Chad,  Thanks again, and once again I'll look this over and post a comment.

Comment: Chad,  Thanks for trying to help, but this is too much for me to even attempt to comprehend.  Jackson

Answer (score 0):

I have been "in contact" with PayPal over this very problem ever since they changed their method of notification in March. Their last but one missive read:

> Thanks for getting back in touch about your notifications.
>
> I'd like to start by saying I'm sorry for the length of time this has been going on for.  I know it's been quite some time since I originally escalated your issue and I'm saddened to see it's still ongoing.
>
> I've escalated this once more, with a note to request the previous escalations are looked into as well.  I've requested that one of my supervisors get back to you to address your complaint and give you the full explanation you need.  This will be within 72 hours.
>
> Thank you for your time.
>
> Yours sincerely,
> Gemma
> UK Top Customer Department
> PayPal

Needless to say, four weeks later I had to get on to them again and again received a similar apology.

Somewhere along the line, one PayPal operative explained the reason for the changes as:

> The reason in which this has changed is due sellers responding directly to buyers rather than corresponding within our system, this is mainly relevant to disputes and claims. However, if you respond through the PayPal system it is recorded.

I have asked them endlessly to explain this but got nowhere. I shall continue to bombard them with disgruntled complaints!

They are however, aware that it's not just me who is disgruntled and as a one man band, worried about taking any time away from my computer.

My complaints have been going to:

europeanservices@paypal.com